# Copying element of Char array into short

Tags: c++, c

Which is the best way to copy char array element into short?

Suppose we have -

```
char arr[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
unsigned short *value = 0;
```

1) `*value = (unsigned short*) arr[4];`

2) `*value = *((unsigned short *) ((void *) &arr[4]));`

3) Take a temporary variable -

```
unsigned short temp;
memcpy( &temp, &arr[4], sizeof( temp) );
*value = temp;`
```

Moreover Second option is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: You're aware that all of them are undefined behaviour?

Comment: Lacks basic understanding. Pick one of the languages C or C++ and read a good book.

Comment: Learn what pointers are! Learn about what arrays are. Learn what will happen if you change data types with implicit and explicit cast. What is with big and little endian. Please take a book, a course or lets advice you by a friend. What you provide is simply nonsense!

Comment: I know its one of the basic question but I guess Proper solution would be to stop creating and using un-aligned pointer but shouldn't it be handled by compiler like implicit conversion.

Comment: It is not a problem to implicit cast a value from one to another. But as we can see you have no understanding what a pointer does and what memcopy does and how your memory layout looks like. So if you start to copy some memory areas around you have "undefined bahaviour". Your question shows that you have no idea what you are doing. Please try to understand what memory layout is created from your compiler and take a debugger to look into.

Comment: What *exactly* is it that you want to do, and what number do you expect to get as a result?  Based on what your code seems to be attempting, `unsigned short value = arr[4];` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a list of random guesses.

```
value = &temp;
*value = arr[4];
```

might work for your stated goal;

Comment: That won't compile, and it even with a cast it's undefined.

Comment: @NeilKirk Oops! My bad - missed the indirection. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

2 and 3 will copy 2 bytes from your array, which will lead you to copy from unknown memory at the end of your char array.

in 1 you are casting a pointer from a value to unknown area.

you should be doing:

*value = (unsigned short) arr[4];

ie: you cast the char value to an unsigned short and then copy it to whereever value is pointing (hoping it is a valid pointer)

edit: your pointer has a value of 0... so it should be:

```
unsigned short value = (unsigned short) arr[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code will look as

```
char arr[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
unsigned short *value = new unsigned short( arr[4] );
```

Or

```
char arr[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
unsigned short *value = new unsigned short;
*value = arr[4];
```

Take into account that type `char` in your system can behave as `signed char`. So in general case instead of the above statement maybe you need the following

```
char arr[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
unsigned short *value = new unsigned short( ( unsigned char )arr[4] );
```

Though in your example '5' is a positive value and there is no difference between the aboth two code snippets.

Also if you want to store value 5 instead of '5' in the object of type unsigned short then you should write

```
char arr[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
unsigned short *value = new unsigned short( arr[4] - '0' );
```

Or

```
char arr[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
unsigned short *value = new unsigned short;
*value = arr[4] - '0';
```

Comment: `new unsigned short` what??

Comment: @Neil Kirk  I have not understood your question. What do you mean?

Comment: Why are you allocating a short dynamically for no reason?

Comment: @Neil Kirk First of all see the original post. If you will not allocate memory then any assignment statement for *value will be wrong. Moreover the author of the topic already got a segmentation fault because he did not allocate a memory.

Comment: Ok you could explain that but also show alternative not using dynamic memory. A local short should be preferred.

Comment: @Neil Kirk All alternatives are only your fantasies. The original code is not about alternatives. Nevertheless you may write your own answer.

Comment: `unsigned short value = arr[4] - '0';`

Comment: @Neil Kirk His post has no any variable defined as value. There is used a pointer. So as I said it is only your fantasies.

Comment: His question is "Which is the best way to copy char array element into short?" He uses a pointer, but possibly because he doesn't know it can be another way, and he maybe doesn't really need a pointer. Your answer can contain suggestions. If you can only imagine pointers to dynamic integers, keep me out of your fantasies.

Comment: @Neil Kirk  All this is your fantasies and nothing more. But in any case you may write your own answer to the post.

Comment: There is no need to be insulting, mister. What I said has already be posted as answer and comment, so no need.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is undefined behavior, As you are casting Char to Short and not sure what will be the first byte stored in word. Means will also depend on endian terminology.